# 2PC with URBcast

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

Two phase commitment can be used for distributed transaction commitment. But it is consider as a blocking protocol when we used it with a best effort broadcast (BEBcast).

My first question is, can we overcome "blocking" using 2PC (two phase commitment) with Uniform reliable broadcast (URBcast)?
 if it can, then what are the limitations if we compared it with a 3PC (three phase commitment) protocol?

Comment: You should explain the terms you are using and provide some context /background and motivation for your question. Please check the links in the "Tips about writing better questions" in [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first question is, can we overcome "blocking" using 2PC (two phase commitment) with Uniform reliable broadcast (URBcast)?

No. 2PC is blocking because the protocol cannot progress when the coordinator crashes between sending the first and second messages, because the followers/cohort/participants wait for the second message. Since for blocking a blocking scenario it is not necessary to see some deliver the message and others not, going for URB will not change anything.